# Forwarding MySQL connection with iptables and differents network interfaces

Tags: linux, mysql, iptables, nat, port-forwarding

I have a PC with Ubuntu as a router. It has a 3G connection with a public IP to the Internet, and there is a private wireless subnet. So it has two active interfaces:

- ppp0: public IP (WAN)
- wlan0: private IP (LAN)

With **iptables** I wannt to **forward every MySQL connection** (port 3306) to a local machine (10.42.43.10) of the subnet.

I type these iptables commands:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i ppp0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to 10.42.43.10:3306
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i ppp0 -o wlan0 -d 10.42.43.10 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

But it doesn't work. telnet publicip 3306 fails :-(

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a ssh tunnel for forwaring the connections. It's much easier and secure than using iptables:

ssh -L YOUR_PUBLIC_IP:3306:10.42.43.10:3306 YOUR_USER@10.42.43.10

You will have to enter the ssh user credentials and the redirection through tunnel will be done. Fast, easy and secure :)

Answer (score 1):

The rules seem correct. I think you have not enabled IP forwarding in kernel.
There are two ways to enable IP forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

This will get reset on reboot. Add the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

And you should be able to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't able to comment on the answer Nilesh posted, so i added this for anyone who might be having problems following that step

in regards to

> `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

this will only work if you are the root user.

you ***should*** do it this way

> `echo -n 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

`echo -n` is so there isn't a trailing newline character

`sudo tee` is so that you can write to the file with increased permissions

`sudo echo > /file` doesn't work if /file needs to be accessed as a root user, because sudo is only operating on the `echo` function and not the `> /file`

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. I’m upvoting this answer because it’s useful for users who aren’t running a shell with superuser privileges. I’d also add that `echo` does not behave consistently across different Unix-like systems; `printf` is much more robust/reliable.